# Print multiple cell values per row in a filtered sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following loop that iterates through a filtered excel sheet

```
Sub SpecialLoop()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A2:A11")

    For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Debug.Print cl
    Next cl

End Sub
```

So this prints all the values from A2 to A11. How can I, within the loop, print the corresponding values in column B as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub SpecialLoop()
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Range("A2:A11").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each cl In rng
            Debug.Print cl ' col A
            Debug.Print cl.Offset(, 1) ' col B
            'alternative way
            'Debug.Print Range("B" & cl.Row) ' col B
        Next cl
    End If
End Sub
```

If there is no visible cell `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` triggers an error, that's why I'm using `On Error Resume Next` and `If Not rng Is Nothing Then`.

As for you original question, you can use `Debug.Print cl.Offset(, 1)` to get value from column B (assuming that `cl` refers to cell in column A). Or alternative way, more explicit: `Debug.Print Range("B" & cl.Row)`